# Summation of non-principal real Dirichlet character

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, characters

Let $q > 3$ be a prime and 
$$
S_q := \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} \chi_{2,q} (k) \, k,
$$
where
$\chi_{2,q}$ is the real [Dirichlet character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) modulo $q$ which is not the principal one.

I have to prove that $S_q$ is always divisible by $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I'm right:

Let $w$ be a primitive root modulo $q$. Then every congruence class $1, 2, \dots, q-1$ is reached exactly once when we consider $w^0, w^1, \dots, w^{q-2}$
modulo $q$. So we can rewrite $S_q$ as following
$$
S_q := \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} \chi_{2,q} (k) \, k = \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} w^k.
\chi_{2,q} (w^k)
$$
Since
$$
\chi_{2,q} (w^k) = (-1)^k
$$
we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{q-1} w^k \chi_{2,q} (w^k) = \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} (-w)^k.
$$
This is equal to
$$
\frac{(-w)^{q-1} - 1}{-w-1} \equiv 0 \quad \mod q
$$
by Fermat's Little Theorem. We observe that $-w \not\equiv 1$ since $q>3$.

Comment: $k$ in $\chi_{2,q} (k)$ is an integer. Is $w^k$ an integer for any $k\in[1,q-1]$?

Answer (score 1):

Starter hint: $\chi$ acts as a group homomorphism $(\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z)^\times\to\{\pm1\}$. The kernel is precisely those elements which are *squares*. (Thus, $\chi$ is the so-called Legendre symbol.) Try to convince yourself using your knowledge of cyclic groups! So $\chi_q(k)$ is $+1$ if $k$ is a square and is $-1$ if $k$ isn't. Rewrite the sum; see if you can identify *simpler* sums (which you can find closed-forms for) it can be expressed in terms of, while thinking of all summands and the sum itself as taking place in $\Bbb F_q$.

I am amenable to providing more hints if you need more help with the argument.

Comment: Thanks I did't know about Legendre symbol.